# Running docker push --insecure-registries from CI command line or at least without root access?

Tags: docker

First, this is not the FAQ about [how](https://docs.docker.com/registry/insecure/) to put:

```
{ "insecure-registries" : ["myregistrydomain.com:5000"] }
```

in `/etc/docker/daemon.json`. I know about that. And that works. If you have root access. Which I don't.

So one wording of this question is:

Is there a good reason that `docker push` doesn't allow for a `--insecure-registry` option? Is there some other way to do this without root access? Or is there a way I've overlooked?

Background: We want to push an image from a build server to a private registry we've set up. We cannot get an HTTPS certificate for the private registry for various internal reasons. And we don't have root access to the build server. This together means we can't push to our private registry from docker.

I *have* gotten to work with a hack. I first build the docker image and then save the image to a tar file with

```
docker image save image:tag >  image.tar
```

then copy `image.tar` to another server running docker, where I do have root access and have edited `/etc/docker/daemon.json`, and push to the private repository from there.

This "other server" can be a real other server or a short-lived docker image, running [Docker-in-docker aka docker:dind](https://hub.docker.com/_/docker) on the build server.

Since I *can* do this with a docker-in-docker image without root access, there seems to be no security reason why `docker push --insecure-registry server/image:tag` is not possible. So now I wonder: Why is that not possible or is there something I've overlooked?

Comment: (You can use Docker to edit that file directly – if you can run any `docker` command, you have unrestricted root access on the host – but that's probably not quite what you're asking.)